# OSX “Microsoft Remote Desktop (MSRD)” redefine shortcut not works

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, microsoft

Typically on OSX remaping of keyboard shortcuts works well.

In "Microsoft Remote Desktop (MSRD)" it works well too but previous keystrokes still exist:

```
OSX > System Preferences > Keyboard > App Shortcuts > Add
Application: "Microsoft Remote Desktop"
Menu Title: "Close Connection"
Keyboard Shortcut: "Alt+Shift+W"
```

I can close with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and also with the default <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

This is not OSX default behaviour so I think it is BUG.

---

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug too.

As it has 2 versions of Close, both Close Connection & just Close [when there's no window open] I thought adding *both* those as key commands would do it - but no,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>   still closes the connection.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's likely a bug as I can confirm that this is working in MSRD beta version. https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/5e0c144289a51fca2d3bfa39ce7f2b06/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).   - From Review